# Using aggregate on documents that contain arrays?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that contains documents with a structure like below:

```
{
   answers: [
      {
          Title: 'What's your age?',
          values: [
                      {value: true, label: '18-30'}
                  ]
      },
      {
          Title: 'What's your favorite color(s)?',
          values: [
                      {value: true, label: 'Red'},
                      {value: true, label: 'Green'}
                  ]
      }
   ]
},
{
   answers: [
      {
          Title: 'What's your age?',
          values: [
                      {value: true, label: '31-40'}
                  ]
      },
      {
          Title: 'What's your favorite color(s)?',
          values: [
                      {value: true, label: 'Red'}
                  ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I'd like to get the counts for the various answers.  So for the above data I'd like to get something like:

```
{
   {
      Title: "What's your age?",
      AgeTotals: {
        "18-30": 1,
        "31-40": 1
      }
   },
   {
      Title: "What's your favorite color(s)?",
      ColorTotals: {
        "Red": 2,
        "Green": 1
      }
   }
}
```

My first thought was to do something like this:

```
db.test.aggregate(
    {$unwind: "$answers"},
    {$unwind: "$answers.values"},
    {$group:{
        _id: "$answers.values.label",
        totals: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
);
```

But this generates the output:

```
{ "_id" : "31-40", "totals" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "Red", "totals" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "Green", "totals" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "18-30", "totals" : 1 }
```

How would I go about getting the totals for each answer rather than the above?

UPDATE:

Alternatively I would be ok if the data were output in the following format:

```
{ "title: "What's your age?", "_id" : "31-40", "totals" : 1 }
{ "title": "What's your favorite color?", "_id" : "Red", "totals" : 2 }
{ "title": "What's your favorite color?", "_id" : "Green", "totals" : 1 }
{ "title: "What's your age?", "_id" : "18-30", "totals" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got pretty close.

- You need to add `answers.Title` to the first group `_id`, to get it
  listed on the document.
- `Group` the records once again based on the answer title, and
  accumulate the counts for various labels using the [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) operator.

Updated Code:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$answers"},
    {$unwind: "$answers.values"},
    {$group:{"_id": {"answer":"$answers.Title",
                     "label":"$answers.values.label"},
              "totals": {$sum: 1}}
    },
    {$group:{"_id":"$_id.answer",
             "totals":{$push:{"label":"$_id.label",
                              "count":"$totals"}}}} 
]);
```

Sample o/p:

```
{
        "_id" : "What's your favorite color(s)?",
        "totals" : [
                {
                        "label" : "Green",
                        "count" : 1
                },
                {
                        "label" : "Red",
                        "count" : 2
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "What's your age?",
        "totals" : [
                {
                        "label" : "31-40",
                        "count" : 1
                },
                {
                        "label" : "18-30",
                        "count" : 1
                }
        ]
}
```

When you say, you want to get the below output:

```
{
   {
      Title: "What's your age?",
      AgeTotals: {
        "18-30": 1,
        "31-40": 1
      }
   },
   {
      Title: "What's your favorite color(s)?",
      ColorTotals: {
        "Red": 2,
        "Green": 1
      }
   }
}
```

You notice that the output contains a `value` field as its `key`. (The value of the field label - "Red", is a key.). The Aggregation framework has limits, one of its limits is that a value from a field cannot be transformed into a key in the output document. To achieve that you need to perform map-reduce.

Answer (score 1):

For your alternative output you could do:

```
db.test.aggregate([
{"$unwind": "$answers"},
{"$group": {'_id': {"title": "$answers.Title", "value": "$answers.values.label" }}},
{"$unwind": "$_id.value"},
{"$group": {"_id": {"title": "$_id.title", "value": "$_id.value"}, "total": {"$sum": 1}}},
{"$project": {"title": "$_id.title", "value": "$_id.value", "total": 1, "_id": 0}}])
```

Which produces:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "total" : 1,
            "title" : "What's your age?",
            "value" : "18-30"
        }, 
        {
            "total" : 1,
            "title" : "What's your favorite color(s)?",
            "value" : "Green"
        }, 
        {
            "total" : 2,
            "title" : "What's your favorite color(s)?",
            "value" : "Red"
        }, 
        {
            "total" : 1,
            "title" : "What's your age?",
            "value" : "31-40"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

This output has the benefit of a consistence structure where only meta-data is stored as keys.